# JQuery Get Parent URL in IFrame:iframe and its parent are in Different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am struggling to get parenet URL inside my  iframe (ie the url showing in browser). My parent site is gslb13.aaa.com .Inside there is an iframe in which i am loading my site `test.elasticbeanstalk.com` (notice both are in different domain) 
Onclicking `smile` link in `gslb13.aaa.com`. It will load `test.elasticbeanstalk.com` inside iframe.

To get the parent url I tried with

```
var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location;
alert(url);
```

I am getting the parent URL in index page of test.elasticbeanstalk.com (on load).
then:

1) I clicked "Add" buttons in the test.elasticbeanstalk.com to go to next view

2) Repeated the same code in add.jspx to get the same parent URL

But unfortunately I am getting the URL of test.elasticbeanstalk.com(Not Parent URL:gslb13.aaa.com )

Can Any one suggest me a way to handle  this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.

The same origin security rules prohibit it.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

You need to pass the URL of the parent page with the get request, ortherwise there is no reliable way to get the "parent" url.

You would need the iframe like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
url = encodeURIComponent(document.location.href);
document.write('<iframe src="http://test.elasticbeanstalk.com/something.php?refer='+url+'"></iframe>');
</script>
```

Comment: parent site is out of my control.SO I cant write any code there

Answer (score 7):

use

```
document.referrer;
```

**[Refer This](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp)**

Comment: @user1575713 That is because when you load a new page in your site the previous page would be the referrer. You could append a query string to the links on the index page to store the initial referrer

Comment: @Brian: Yup ..I am agreeing with you..But I have 8 buttons like this in each view ,Appending query string in all places will create confusion .I am wondering is there no way to get the current browser URL even if i am inside iFrame?Is JQuery is not advanced as expected?

Comment: @user1575713 Not a jquery issue really. You could perhaps add a common script that intercepts your links and appends the iframe referrer.